# How do I retrieve the outputs of SVN merge via shell script

Tags: bash, shell, svn

This is my First day @shell scripting.
I am trying to automate the "svn merge" process for my branches.
I have a written a shell script for it, which is executed depending on my requirements.
Now, the conflicts that arise in our code are pretty much standard so I can handle them in the script.

My Doubt :
when I execute the command

`svn merge ^/trunk ^/branch`

The output  going to stdout is displayed in terminal, however when executing through shell script I want to redirect it to a file and the `echo` it.
This is what I am doing to achieve it:

`svn merge ^/trunk ^/branch > mergelog`

`cat mergelog`

However, when I check there's no file called mergelog that is created.
Can you please help me with this, please excuse my ignorance this is my first day at scripting.

Comment: you tried the above commands in terminal and the file is not getting created?

Comment: Yes even in terminal the file mergelog is never created.

Comment: Am i using the redirector operator ">" right ?

Comment: can you try redirecting to a different path? could be a permission problem.

Comment: I tired that too , it doesnt work :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to capture svn Merge Information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21433549/how-to-capture-svn-merge-information)