# How to capture svn Merge Information

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have checked out the trunk and have done a merge from branch to trunk. Now all the changes made in branch are present in my trunk working copy. If I do a commit on this working copy, is there any way to identify later that it was a merge and not like a normal checkout-modify-checkin. I can specify the merge details in the log, but I am interested if SVN has some methods to identify and track this.

I have seen in other version control tools like clearcase, a merge arrow will come in the version tree, for each merges. Is there anything like that (some merge symbol or merge arrow) we have for SVN?

Comment: `svn log -g` in /trunk?

Comment: I can specify the merge details in the log, but I am interested if SVN has some methods to identify and track merges apart from this logs. After merge, I can checkin into the trunk even without a commit message. In this case how I will track the merge later.

Comment: `svn log -g` shows entries for the merged entries as well as the entry for the revision that merged it.  So say you merged r123, r124 and r126 from your branch to trunk in r129.  If you run `svn log -c 129 -g` you'll get the log for r129 followed by r123, r124, and r126.  The merged revisions will have a line like "Merged via: r129" or "Reverse merged via: r129".  So he's not just pointing you towards the log you write.

Comment: Thanks Lazy Badger & Ben

Answer (score 3):

Alternative to Ben's mergeinfo method

Let's inspect such (test) repository

[image]

with branch and some cross-nodes merges in process

Log for branch (lazy log, without --stop-on-copy)

```
reading>svn log -g -q -v
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r7 | Badger | 2014-01-30 13:51:41 +0600 (Чт, 30 янв 2014)
Changed paths:
   M /branches/reading/1.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r6 | Badger | 2014-01-30 13:50:34 +0600 (Чт, 30 янв 2014)
Changed paths:
   M /branches/reading
   M /branches/reading/1.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r5 | Badger | 2014-01-30 13:43:45 +0600 (Чт, 30 янв 2014)
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/1.txt
Merged via: r6
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r4 | Badger | 2014-01-30 13:42:59 +0600 (Чт, 30 янв 2014)
Changed paths:
   M /branches/reading/1.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r3 | Badger | 2014-01-30 13:39:37 +0600 (Чт, 30 янв 2014)
Changed paths:
   A /branches/reading (from /trunk:2)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | Badger | 2014-01-30 13:36:46 +0600 (Чт, 30 янв 2014)
Changed paths:
   A /trunk/1.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | Badger | 2014-01-30 13:35:19 +0600 (Чт, 30 янв 2014)
Changed paths:
   A /branches
   A /tags
   A /trunk
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Even without log-message in r6 `Merged via: r6` from r5 clearly states: r6 is mergeset, where trunk's HEAD (r5) was merged into branch

Log (relevant part of) for trunk

```
WC>svn log -g -q -v
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r8 | Badger | 2014-01-30 13:56:09 +0600 (Чт, 30 янв 2014)
Changed paths:
   M /trunk
   M /trunk/1.txt
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r7 | Badger | 2014-01-30 13:51:41 +0600 (Чт, 30 янв 2014)
Changed paths:
   M /branches/reading/1.txt
Merged via: r8
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r6 | Badger | 2014-01-30 13:50:34 +0600 (Чт, 30 янв 2014)
Changed paths:
   M /branches/reading
   M /branches/reading/1.txt
Merged via: r8
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r4 | Badger | 2014-01-30 13:42:59 +0600 (Чт, 30 янв 2014)
Changed paths:
   M /branches/reading/1.txt
Merged via: r8
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r3 | Badger | 2014-01-30 13:39:37 +0600 (Чт, 30 янв 2014)
Changed paths:
   A /branches/reading (from /trunk:2)
Merged via: r8
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`Merged via: r8` in log records for r3:r7 show next mergepoint (at this time - from branch to trunk)

In short: mergeinfo show **what** was merged, log -g - **what and when**

Answer (score 2):

You should see that there are changes to the `svn:mergeinfo` property on one or more paths.  This is used to [track what was merged](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.mergeinfo).  You can then use the `svn mergeinfo` command to see what paths have been merged or are eligible to be merged from a source branch to another branch.  `svn mergeinfo` can also display a somewhat crude graph for the merge if you don't pass it a `--show-revs` argument in 1.8.  As [Dipu H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2492443/dipu-h) already mentioned in his comment you can also see merged revisions with the `-g` option to `svn log`.

Based on your tag it seems that you're using TortoiseSVN.  As far as I know TortoiseSVN doesn't have a way to visualize the mergeinfo with the revision graph feature it has.  [Smart SVN](http://www.wandisco.com/smartsvn/home) is a commercial Subversion client that [has such a feature](http://www.wandisco.com/smartsvn/features#revision-graph) (full disclosure I work for the company that produces Smart SVN).  [Subclipse has such a feature](http://subclipse.tigris.org/graph.html) as well if you're using Eclipse.  There is a plugin for [JetBrains IDEs as well](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6178?pr=phpStorm).

So I'm sure if you searched you'll find something that works for you.  But I don't know enough about your environment to point you in any particular direction.